# SQL syntax ERROR in ALTER TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

while trying to delete a coloumn and add again i am getting this error.
coding php with mysql
ERROR:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version                                                                                                                                    for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE logindatabase DROP COLOUMN id' at line 1

```
CODE:
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','sagar');//connecting database
//resting our table.....deleting error rows.....reseting autoincremented values
$q_reset_table="DELETE FROM logindatabase WHERE username = NULL;
            ALTER TABLE logindatabase DROP COLOUMN id ;
            ALTER TABLE logindatabase ADD id int(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment; ";
mysqli_query($con, $q_reset_table) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Is this sql-server or mysql? They are NOT the same thing.

Comment: @SeanLange seeing as this is using `mysqli_query`, it should be MySQL

Comment: @tepples It's what's causing the error I guess

Comment: it was a typo.... not the cause of problem .... still exist @tepples and @ Lamak

Comment: The problem is because you're sending three SQL statements; `mysqli_query` is for a single statement. You can either run each statement separately, or use `mysqli_multi_query` to run all three.

Answer (score 1):

Sql for deleting should be
`DELETE FROM logindatabase WHERE username IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reset the autoincrement values try

```
ALTER TABLE logindatabase AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER TABLE logindatabase DROP COLOUMN id

COLOUMN is wrong, COLUMN is the word to use.